# Sum Every Input in Dynamic Table using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a table where user can add row. And on specific column, there is an input where user can insert a value and jQuery will sum all the value and insert it to another input

So, to make it clear, here's an example:

[example](http://syafiqaz.my/sumall.html)

The problem is, after I add more row, it won't sum all the input. It will only sum the FIRST input of the FIRST row but it won't sum when I insert a value in the second, third, forth and ... input.

Here's the table:

```
<table id="twe">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th valign="middle"><center>Amaun</center></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input name="amount[]" type="text" class="amount" id="amount[]" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

<button type="button" onclick="addrow('twe')"  title="Add">Add</button>
<br/>
<br/>
Sum: <input type="text" id="sum" />
```

And here's the script

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.currencyFormat = function() {
        this.each( function( i ) {
            $(this).change( function( e ){
                if( isNaN( parseFloat( this.value ) ) ) return;
                this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
            });
        });
        return this; //for chaining
    }
})( jQuery );

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.amount').currencyFormat();

});


$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".amount").each(function () {

     $(this).keyup(function () {
         calculateSum();
     });
 });

});

function calculateSum() {

 var sum = 0;
 $(".amount").each(function () {

     if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
         sum += parseFloat(this.value);
     }

 });
 $("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
 }


 function addrow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;

            }
        }
}
```

Same goes with the input currency. It only works on the first input of the first row.

Need help

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in when you are binding the events.  In your `document.ready` function you are looping through the `.amount` items and binding a keyup, but this doesn't account for FUTURE items that will be created.  What you want to do is bind all instances AND future instances to run the calculation.

This can be done using the [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event in jQuery.  Your `document.ready` would be updated as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("keyup", ".amount", calculateSum);
});
```

**Working Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/p2Hbm/

Comment: Thanks!

Now the next problem is I have made the .amount input to decimal using a jQuery .toFixed(), however, it only works for the first row

Comment: sorry for not explain it clear enough. I have updated my questions. Hopes that is clear

Comment: My answer applies to the second part of your question.  The problem occurs on HOW you're binding the events.  Read my answer, and try to apply it for your new problem.